# Weird font definition

Tags: fonts

What does the following code mean? Its zeros look odd.

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{FiraSans-OsF}{m}{n}{
      <-0> \FiraSans@@scale FiraSans-Book-osf-t1
      <0-> \FiraSans@@scale FiraSans-Regular-osf-t1
}{}
```

The code is found in [T1FiraSans-OsF.fd](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fira/latex/T1FiraSans-OsF.fd).

Comment: Odd, but not illegal: `<-> \FiraSans@@scale FiraSans-Book-osf-t1` would be more standard. Sometimes `autoinst` does funny things.

Comment: Do you mean that Regular cannot be used?

Comment: Sorry, I should have modified the second line, with `Regular`.

Comment: I have mailed the package maintainer who answered that he's investigating over the issue.

Comment: The bugs have been fixed! Thanks to Bob Tennent (for `FiraSans`) and Marc Penninga (for `autoinst`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that sometimes `autoinst` does funny things. Possibly a bad parameter has been passed when the font family infrastructure has been built. And no, the Book variant will never be used.

In general a syntax such as

```
<x-y> s*[<mag>] fontfile
```

means that LaTeX should use `fontfile` (with `<mag>` magnification) when it is requested the stated font combination at sizes greater than `x` and less than or equal to `y`. It's TeX's job to look at the font's design size and load it at a scale.

If `x` is missing, then all sizes less than or equal to `y` will use that `fontfile`; if `y` is missing, then the `fontfile` will be used at sizes greater than `x`.

The macro `\FiraSans@@scale` will expand to nothing or to `s*[<mag>]`, so it's not relevant.

That declaration is completely equivalent to

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{FiraSans-OsF}{m}{n}{
      <-> \FiraSans@@scale FiraSans-Regular-osf-t1
}{}
```

as fonts cannot be loaded at a size less than or equal to 0.

This is theory, practice seems to be different. `:-(`

Apparently, these font declarations have the effect of choosing the *first* line for every setup. Indeed, the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{FiraSans}

\begin{document}

Normal: \fontname\font

Bold: \textbf{\fontname\font}

Italic: \textit{\fontname\font}

BoldItalic: \textbf{\textit{\fontname\font}}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

which is not what's expected.

A clear bug in the package, I'd say. If I copy the `.fd` file and remove the `<-0>` lines, the above document produces

[image]

Besides, the `book` option does nothing sensible, as the `k` weight is nowhere defined in the `.fd` files.

## Update 2018-01-10

The package `FiraSans` has been updated and the bugs have been fixed.

Now the faulty entry reads

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{FiraSans-OsF}{m}{n}{
      <-> \FiraSans@@scale FiraSans-Regular-osf-t1
}{}
```

as it should.

Now the example above typesets

[image]

If we add the `book` option to the call of `FiraSans`, the output is

[image]

as advertised in the documentation.

Comment: Using a slightly revised autoinst, a corrected fira package has been produced and uploaded to CTAN.